# How to parametrize fields of a SELECT statement?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Is there a way to parametrize fields of a SELECT statement using `PreparedStatement` or other utilities?

I mean something like:

`SELECT ?, ? FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ? = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JDBC does not let you do that. The idea behind parameters is to speed up execution and avoid SQL interjections; parameterizing the columns that you are selecting does not help either of these two goals.

Comment: I'm also using Spring Framework and `JdbcTemplate`... Can this help me?

Comment: No, as far as I understand, JdbcTemplate takes "regular" SQL, and passes it through to JDBC. You would need to build your own SQL templating library - assuming that your SQL statements are mostly "canned" with some flexibility in the column lists and expressions, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @davioooh As far as JDBC goes, it does not let you do even more sensible stuff, such as `select * from mytable where myfield in (?)`, where `?` represents an "in list". They force you to add a question mark for each element of your "in list", which leads to duplication of even basic canned statements.

Comment: There is atemplate library called [SQLind](http://www.sqlind.net/#Getting%20started) that seems to do exactly that. You might like to give it a look.

Comment: Thank you @edalorzo but I was hoping to achieve this using plain JDBC. I would avoid using a new framework only for this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight so I think I have to concatenate strings to obtain my parametrized query, as **sarwar026** suggested in is answer...

Comment: @davioooh I would use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for that.

Comment: @davioooh like this: `String sql = String.format("select %s, %s from my_table where %s = ?", "one", "two", "code");`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: so you are suggesting to do something like:
`"SELECT " + field1 + ", " + field2 + " FROM MY_TABLE"`
right?